# how can manipulatean array of objects in an esper rule or how can I define a property of an event as a collection of another event

Tags: esper

I have defined as schemas

```
CREATE  SCHEMA  Sensor (
                timestamp       long
            ,   machine_id      string
            ,   oil_temp_in     double, oil_temp_out        double
            ,   oil_flow        double, overshoot_angle     double
            )
CREATE  SCHEMA  Alarm   (   machine_id  string, ts_Start    long
                        ,   ts_End      long,   type        string  )
```

the Alarm detection is based on certain conditions with the properties of the sensor event. There are several types.

```
CREATE  SCHEMA  AlarmRelevant ( machine_id  string, ts          long
                            ,   type        string, source      Alarm [] )
```

And a named window unique per sensor / alarm type that takes the number of alarms that have occurred on the day.

```
CREATE  SCHEMA  AlarmsPerDayAndType_Wnd (machine_id string, type string
    , ts long, number integer, active   boolean, source Alarm []    )

CREATE  WINDOW wnd_AlarmsPerDayAndType.std:unique(machine_id,type)  AS AlarmsPerDayAndType_Wnd;
```

it is considered that an alarm is relevant when more than 15 alarms of the same type and sensor occur in one day, and we need take the top 15 alarms

I do not know how to initialize the array of alarms, and add elements, when the alarms are triggered, I tried it with {}, and {} .Union ({a}) but I get an error that is a collecion

```
ON  AlarmUC1    (ts_End IS  NULL)   a 
    MERGE   wnd_AlarmsPerDayAndType w 
    WHERE   a.type  =   w.type
    WHEN    MATCHED 
    THEN    UPDATE
                SET number  =   CASE    WHEN a.ts_Start.roundFloor('day') = initial.ts.roundFloor('day') 
                                        THEN initial.number + 1
                                        ELSE 1
                                END
                ,   ...
                ,   source  
                =   CASE WHEN a.ts_Start.roundFloor('day') = initial.ts.roundFloor('day') 
                        THEN initial.source.Union({a})***Error
                        ELSE {a}    *** Error
                    END     
    WHEN    NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT  (machine_id, type, ts, number, active, source)
            SELECT  a.machine_id,a.type,a.ts_Start,1,false,    {a} *** Error
```

My questions are:
how can manipulate (empty, add, ... ) an array of objects in an esper rule
**or** how can I define a property of an event as a collection of another event.

Comment: I would propose to simplify this question by removing anything that doesn't have to do with the question. Who cares about "oil_temp_in"?

Comment: ok. 
if I understand it's not possible with a sentence 'create schema'  define a property that is a java.util.Collection, then I have to work with arrays. 
how can I express in an esper sentence an empty array, an how to append new elements to it?

Comment: create schema StockTick(symbol string, prices java.util.Collection);  --works fine

Comment: Call a UDF that returns a new appended array. Or just simply use "window" aggregation functions together with table and into-table aggregation instead.